# Status com cores na gridview asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, enums, cores

Eu preciso fazer com que o textos dos status dos exames de um app apareçam com cores diferentes, no caso espera preto, marcado verde e não realizado em vermelho, esses status estão em um Enum. Segue meu código, se alguém souber a melhor forma para essa implementação.

```
                                      @model List<Phil.Odontomedicas.Core.ExameSolicitado>
            @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Exames Solicitados";
              }
            <div class="well">
           @using (Html.BeginForm("Filtrar", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
              {
                @Html.Partial("_Filters")
               }
          </div>
           <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                     <table class="table table-striped dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap" id="grdExames">
                          <thead>
                          <tr>
                          <td>Dentista</td>
                          <td>Paciente</td>
                          <td>Telefone Paciente</td>
                          <td>Data Solicitação</td>
                          <td>Cupom</td>
                          <td>Status</td>
                          <td>Exame</td>
                          <td>Detalhes Exame</td>
                          <td>Marcado/Realizado/Não Marcado</td>
                           </tr>
                         </thead>
                       <tbody>
                          @foreach (var exame in Model.OrderByDescending(x => x.DataSolicitado))
                          {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@exame.Dentista.Nome</td>
                            <td>@exame.Paciente.Nome</td>
                            <td>@exame.Paciente.Telefone</td>
                            <td>@exame.DataSolicitado.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>
                            <td>@exame.Cupom</td>
                            <td>@exame.StatusExame.ToString()</td>
                            <td>@exame.ExameTitulo</td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-sm detalhe-exame btn-default" data-detalhe="@exame.DadosExame" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Detalhes Exame</button></td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-id="@exame.Id" data-tipo="1" onclick="GravarExame(this,event)"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-id="@exame.Id" data-tipo="4" onclick="GravarExame(this,event)"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></button> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-id="@exame.Id" data-tipo="3" onclick="GravarExame(this,event)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                      </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
                 </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
                            <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
                               <div class="modal-dialog">
                               <div class="modal-content">
                               <div class="modal-header">
                                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                              <h4 class="modal-title">Descrição Exame</h4>
                               </div>
                              <div class="modal-body" id="modalDescricao">

                             </div>
                        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                   </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                            </div><!-- /.modal -->
                               @section Javascript{
                                   <script type="text/javascript">
                              function GravarExame(elemento, event) {
                                     event.preventDefault();
                        var elemId = $(elemento).attr("data-id");
                        var elemTipo = $(elemento).attr("data-tipo");


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/Atualizar")',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            data: "{'Id':'" + elemId + "','StatusExame':" + elemTipo + "}",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Ocorreu um erro, entre em contato com o desenvolvedor!");
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.detalhe-exame').on("click", function () {
            var detalhes = $(this).attr("data-detalhe");
            $('#modalDescricao').html("");
            $('#modalDescricao').html(detalhes);
        });

        $("#grdExames").DataTable({
            searching: false,
            ordering: false,
            "language": {
                "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix": "",
                "sInfoThousands": ".",
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
                "sProcessing": "Processando...",
                "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sNext": "Próximo",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                    "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                    "sLast": "Último"
                           },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu faria assim:

Criaria as classes de CSS para cada status:

```
<style>
    .preto { /* definições aqui */ }
    .vermelho {  /* definições aqui */ }
    .verde { /* definições aqui */ }
</style>
```

Então no foreach faria um switch.

```
@foreach (var exame in Model.OrderByDescending(x => x.DataSolicitado))
{
   string classe = "";
   switch(exame.StatusExame)
   {
     case Status.Espera : classe = "preto"; break;
     case Status.Marcado : classe = "verde"; break;
     case Status.NaoRealizado : classe = "vermelho"; break;
     default : break;
   }

   .....
   <td class="@classe">@exame.StatusExame.ToString()</td>
}
```

Você poderia também em vez de usar o atributo `class` utilizar `<font color="@cor">@exame.StatusExame.ToString()</font>` nesse caso mudando o switch:

```
       string cor = "";
       switch(exame.StatusExame)
       {
         case Status.Espera : cor = "#000000"; break;
         case Status.Marcado : cor = "#008000"; break;
         case Status.NaoRealizado : cor = "#FF0000"; break;
         default : break;
       }
```